# How to map endpoints that get changed by Octopus for different environments in NServiceBus 7?

Tags: c#, nservicebus, .net-4.8

I'm upgrading NServiceBus to version 7 and the configuration block `<UnicastBusconfig>` in `app.config` has been deprecated according to the upgrade [guide](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/upgrades/6to7/#configuration-endpoint-mappings) and should now be configured in-code.

In my `app.config` the endpoints get changed by Octopus, depending on which environment I'm deploying to (dev/staging/prod).

```
<UnicastBusConfig>
  <MessageEndpointMappings>
    <add Messages="project_A" Endpoint="project_A_dev" />
    <add Messages="project_B" Endpoint="project_B_dev" />
    <add Messages="project_C" Endpoint="project_C_dev" />
    <add Messages="project_D" Endpoint="project_D_dev" />
  </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

How can I map these endpoints in-code and have them still overwritable by Octopus?

Answer (score 1):

How to upgrade is [described here](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/upgrades/6to7/#configuration-endpoint-mappings). Because when .NET Core was released, the default was configuration in code over application configuration files like `app.config` and `web.config`.

However, mapping of messages to endpoints should not change from testing to production. It is possible that with MSMQ, your machine names might change. There's an alternative with [FileBasedRouting](https://github.com/timbussmann/NServiceBus.FileBasedRouting). This was an original [NServiceBus project in ParticularLabs](https://github.com/ParticularLabs/NServiceBus.FileBasedRouting) but migrated to Tim Bussmann his repo.

Although [MSMQ is considered dead](https://particular.net/blog/msmq-is-dead). You might want to start using the [NServiceBus Bridge](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/bridge/) to move away from MSMQ onto another transport, because at some point Microsoft will remove support and remove it from Windows. If you'd like more info on the Bridge, [contact support](https://particular.net/support) at Particular Software. If you'd like, mention my name and I'll respond ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Does this mean that we shouldn't be using different endpoints for different environments and I should just have something like "project_A" for dev/staging/prod?

Comment: I'll take a look at NServiceBus Bridge. I wasn't aware of it. In the next few months or so I will be migrating away from MSMQ to Amazon SQS or something similar. I want to make sure that everything still works as expected after upgrading NServiceBus versions (from 4 -> 7) before changing transports.

Comment: Good choice making sure everything works first. Don't want to tackle two problems at the same time. Migrating to another transports requires considerations. If you ever would like to speak to someone, contact us. We love to help out setting you up for a new system (with a PoC for example) or with best practices or anything. Like with the endpoints questions: You are right, you initially design/create logical endpoints like "Finance.Billing" and "Finance.Invoicing" and have (other) endpoints send messages to those. That indeed doesn't change from one environment to the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to have different endpoints for a message based on environment then you can use your own settings in an app.config that are read into the code configuration for the destination.

```
routing.RouteToEndpoint(
    assembly: typeof(AcceptOrder).Assembly,
    @namespace: "PriorityMessages",
    destination: "READ_THIS_FROM_app.config");
```

You can then use Octopus to modify those config settings based on your environment.